# What is the parent of the linear layout in my code?

Tags: java, android, button

This is my code currently

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
       android:layout_weight = "1"
       android:layout_width = "0dp"
       android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
       android:hint = "@string/edit_message" />
   <Button
       android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
       android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
       android:text = "@string/submit"
       android:onClick = "sendMessage"  />


</LinearLayout>
```

I researched the term match_parent and found it to be to match "size of parent layout"(Src: http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/difference-between-wrap-content-and-fill-parentmatch-parent/)

For a button if i specify match_parent, i know the parent would be the linear layout. My question if i specify match_parent on the linear layout, what parent would it match? What would be the term for that parent?

Comment: **"What would be the term for that parent?"** : There's no clear answer to that. It would be acceptable to use the layout you've shown as a `ListView` list item. In that case each instance of that layout would be inflated into a child view of the `ListView` and there would be as many as there are items in the list's adapter. You could also use that layout as the main view of a `Fragment` which may also be on screen with other fragments held in 'containers' such as `FrameLayouts`. If inflated as the layout (content view) of an `Activity` then consider the parent to be the `Window`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent for that LinearLayout can be an activity (so the LinearLayout will be as big as the screen of your device ), or a fragment , or a list/grid item e.t.c. Bassically any viewgroup in witch you include your layout.